# Various collections of resources in a CRUD REST API

Tags: api, twitter, crud

I am curious as to how a CRUD REST API would implement the idea of a `tweets` resource. Of course, an application such as Twitter has the notion of `tweet` objects, but these are needed by the application in various ways ("collections").

Twitter would need an endpoint for `user` timeline (`tweets` published by a certain user) and also for the `home` timeline (the timeline of tweets from people a user is following). I imagine, in a CRUD API, `user` timeline would be located at a URI such as: `tweets?filter={username:"Bob"}`

However, I'm not quite sure how a CRUD API design would implement the `home` timeline collection of tweets. Furthermore, collections such as `favourites` for a user — are these treated as separate resources altogether, or should they somehow be attached to the `tweets` resource?

Furthermore, Twitter have not used the CRUD design for their API. Maybe there is a good reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good thing about resource design is that it doesn't really matter, as long as it makes (some) sense. Obviously some nuances are in place, but let's get to the point. Business models don't (have to) map 1:1 to resources, this is probably why you don't find such relation in the Twitter API.

Some assumptions: Timelines are pre-defined and their behaviour isn't influenceable, other by creating new tweets. Favorites are (references to) tweets. Favorites are influenceable.

A favorite collection resource, could be something like:

- `/user/bob/favorites`

Your "CRUD" operations could be something like:

- `[POST] /user/bob/favorite` { "tweet_id": "343fe4a" } -- Add a new favorite
- `[GET] /user/bob/favorite` -- All favorites, for the user Bob
- `[DELETE] /user/bob/favorite/343fe4a` -- Delete tweet 343fe4a as being favorite

Normally it's best to avoid multiple variables in a single resource, as this introduces a certain complexity that isn't needed. In this example, however, a favorite doesn't have it's own identifier. It instead re-uses the identifier from a tweet and it's also tightly-coupled with a user.

If a favorite does have it's own identifier, I would go about creating a resource like: `/favorite/ef213e13f` this could return meta-data or act as an alias (redirect) to a tweet for a HTTP GET method or a resource to "un-favorite" something (DELETE method).

This statement probably makes more sense if we don't talk about tweets, but instead about a blog with articles and comments:

- `/blog/article/42` -- representing an article
- `/blog/article/42/comments` -- representing a collection to all comments for this article
- `/blog/comment/44571` -- representing a single comment

Depending on what you want, a couple of examples for timelines could be resources like:

1. `/user/bob/timeline/home`
2. `/user/bob/timeline?type=home`
3. `/timeline/home?user=bob`

As I mentioned earlier, it's best to avoid using multiple variables in a resource. I would probably pick option 3. The reasons being, besides the complexity of having too many variables, is that such a resource probably isn't worth caching (client-side) and no CUD actions may be done on it. Since it's most likely an aggregate resource for different entities.

A couple of closing words:

- Design resources first and only then come up with a matching URL
- Don't design resources 1:1 to (business-)models
- Don't over think the situation from the start. Implement something and tinker with it to see possible problems in the future. Once you're happy, put it in production.

Suggestions for further reading:

- HAL - http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html
- Hypermedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypermedia
- RMM - http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html
- Roy Fielding's blog - http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/tag/rest

Comment: Very informative. One of the best answers I've had on Stack Overflow. Thank you @Dynom!

Comment: Shouldn't /user/bob/favorite be PUT instead of POST ?

Comment: PATCH/PUT and POST have mostly a semantical meaning. In this example you're creating a new relationship (=like) between a tweet and a user. Creating stuff is typically a POST request. However if you read it like updating a relationship from nothing to something, then a PUT could be appropriate.

Comment: agreed. But the requests have to be idempotent right

Comment: POST typically isn't, but it can be. It depends on the implementation. In this instance the difference between POST and PUT isn't very significant imho. It becomes very relevant with more complex resources (where a PUT allows you to unset previously defined fields). In this case I would probably handle POST and PUT requests exactly the same.